# Error to access portal gavitee management api

Tags: docker, nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, gravitee

Error to access portal management api.

```
Management API unreachable or error occurs, please check logs
```

I'm using Gravitee 1.27.1, running on the Kubernetes with Nginx Ingress.

Mongo:

ElasticSearch:

```
kubectl create -f . (My files - I'm using cluster)
```

Nginx Ingress:

```
kubectl create -f . (My files)
```

Gravitee:

```
helm install --name api-gateway gravitee -f values.yaml --namespace my-namespace
```

All Pods are Health (ok):

```
kubectl get pod -n my-namespace
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, check in your page, exist HTTP and HTTPS this is a problem. Access with https://api-gateway.mydomain.com. 
Success, I hope it helps!